# Displaying image buttons to replicate app icons - Corona SDK

Tags: button, user-interface, lua, coronasdk

I need to display images so that they mimic the layout of iOS app icons on the various "home" pages. I have the code written to display the various images; however, I cannot figure out how to return a value which corresponds with each individual image on a click event.

Here's my code so far:

```
    plates = {
"fat-burning-foods.jpg",
"fresh_food.jpg",
"fat-burning-foods.jpg",
"star.png",
"fat-burning-foods.jpg",
"star.png",
"fat-burning-foods.jpg",
"fresh_food.jpg",
"fat-burning-foods.jpg",
"star.png",
"fat-burning-foods.jpg",
"fresh_food.jpg",
"fat-burning-foods.jpg",
"star.png"
}


-- The PlateId will have corosponding indexes with the plates array. It will be used to query plate information 

    plateId = {1,2,3,4}
plateIdRef = {}
index = 1
platesIsh = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
local anX = 20
local anY = 120
for i=1, #plates do

 local bufferY = 20
 if index == 4 then
bufferY = 110
anX = 20
elseif index > 4 then
    bufferY = 110

    end
if index == 7 then
    bufferY = 200
    anX = 20

elseif index > 7 then
    bufferY = 200

    if index == 10 then
            bufferY = 290
            anX = 20

        elseif index > 10 then
            bufferY = 290



end

    end


    local dummyVar = math.random()
dummyVar = display.newImageRect(plates[index],80, 80)
sceneGroup:insert(dummyVar)
dummyVar.x = anX + 30
dummyVar.y = anY + bufferY
table.insert(plateIdRef, index)
function dummyVar:touch( event )
if event.phase == "began" then
local alert = native.showAlert( "Corona", event.target, { "OK", "Learn More" } )
    --print( "You touched "..dummyVar)
    return true
end
    end

    dummyVar:addEventListener( "touch", dummyVar )
anX = anX + 110
index = index + 1

end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, an example to see how it works:

```
local plates = {}

local function plateTouch( self, event )
    local phase = event.phase
    if phase == "ended" then
        print( "You touched ".. self.id)
    end
    return true
end

for i=1, 3 do
    plates[i] = display.newImageRect("test.png",80, 80)
    plates[i].id = "plate " .. i
    plates[i].x = 90 * i
    plates[i].y = 90
    plates[i].touch = plateTouch
    plates[i]:addEventListener( "touch", plates[i] )
end
```

When you create each plate you can define an `id` property to know what button was pressed, also you can add any other properties you need.

You can see the [API docs for touch event](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/touch/index.html#TOC) and see the example with table listeners.

Other approach could be object oriented solution, where you define a class to create new plates, but maybe first you need to understand the example.